# Is there a way to force divs into individual subgrids with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've been given a bunch of text I need to display in two columns. Is it possible to use CSS subgrids in a way that different divs are forced into one column or the other? I'd like to display all the `.title`'s in the left column, and the `.card`'s in the right column. Any way to do this? Dynamic example: https://codepen.io/dancanuck/pen/eYMLqzR

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 1em Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 0.3fr 1.4fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title card";
}

.card {
  border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
}

.card h2 {
  background-color: rgba(111, 41, 97, .4);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.card p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.title {
  border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
}

.title h2 {
  background-color: rgba(11, 31, 27, .4);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.title p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <article class="card">
    <h2>This is the heading</h2>
    <p>This is the body of the card.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>This should be in the right column only.</h2>
    <p>This is the body of the card.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>This is the heading</h2>
    <p>This is the body of the card.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Should be in the left column only.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>This is the heading</h2>
    <p>This is the body of the card.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>This is the heading</h2>
    <p>This is the body of the card.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>This is the heading</h2>
    <p>This is the body of the card.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </article>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.card{
grid-area:card;
}
.title{
grid-area:title;
}
```

add grid-area property in .card and .title

Answer (score 0):

Don't use template areas, just assign the elements to their respective column and set the flow to `column`.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 1em Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 0.3fr 1.4fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.card {
  border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-column: 2
}

.card h2 {
  background-color: rgba(111, 41, 97, .4);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.card p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.title {
  border: 5px solid rgb(111, 41, 97);
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.title h2 {
  background-color: rgba(11, 31, 27, .4);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.title p {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <article class="card">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>This should be in the right column only.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>This should be in the right column only.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>This should be in the right column only.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Should be in the left column only.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>This should be in the right column only.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>This should be in the right column only.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>This should be in the right column only.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Should be in the left column only.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```